# Sorting files into directories / uniquely named folders

Tags: windows, powershell, batch, folder-redirection

I have the following problem and I would really appreciate it if I could get some help on that front. I am getting a constant flow of xml files into a folder.
A XML file can look like this. It only goes up to 1005.

```
1001.order-asdf1234.xml
1002.order-asdf4321.xml
```

I want to sort the files into uniquely named folders that are not based on the file names.
A example for that would be

```
Peter (All files with 1001 go in there)
John (All files starting with 1002 go there)
```

How can I create a batch file or a powershell script to continuesly sort files into the specified folders? Since I only have 5 folders I would like to simply specify the target folders and not have elaborate loops but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You already have PowerShell answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68860033/9898643)

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/267099

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method is to execute a `.bat` file that looks like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd C:\path\to\folder
:loop
  move 1001.* 1001
  move 1002.* 1002
  ...
  timeout /t 600 > NUL
goto loop
```

This will loop, doing the move every 10 minutes.
When you want to stop it, just kill it.

An option would be to use the Task Scheduler with a `.bat` file
that just includes the `cd` and `move` commands.
This will avoid the black window displayed by the batch file.